# how do you make a list/file for pacman to install from

Tags: bash, shell-script, arch-linux, pacman

I am trying to move from one arch install a (partitioned one) to another (a less-partitioned one) on my computer and I want a similar set up. So I was wondering if there was a simple way to get pacman to install the same packages.

I was thinking of something like `pacman -Qe | awk '{print $1}' > package_list.txt` then creating a script to install from that list.

Is there a way I can create that script in a few commands or how should I go about doing this?

Comment: You might try packup: https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/packup/ It's a helper script. Also see: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=56601

Comment: i will try that though it does look like a bulky solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pacman -Qeq` instead of `pacman -Qe | awk '{print $1}'`. And pacman can not install AUR packages, better keep them in a separate list or use an AUR helper like `pacaur` or `yaourt`.

So, if you use an AUR helper like pacaur, you can export all explicitly installed packages with:

```
pacman -Qqe > package_list.txt
```

Or if you prefer only native and explicitly installed packages:

```
pacman -Qqen > package_list.txt
```

To install the packages listed in the file:

```
pacman -S - < package_list.txt
```

Replace pacman with pacaur or your AUR helper if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I recently reinstalled arch linux several times, tried using some -Qqe options with pacman, but came across several issues with locally installed packages and such, that I had to comment/remove manually. For me what's worked best is following what the arch wiki says in:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/migrate_installation_to_new_hardware#Bottom_to_top

Generating the package list in an old system:

```
pacman -Qqen > pkglist.txt
pacman -Qqem > pkglist_aur.txt
```

Then (substitute yay for whichever your AUR helper is) on the new system:

```
pacman -S --needed - < pkglist.txt
yay -S --needed - < pkglist_aur.txt
```